# How do you make a string repeat itself in python

Tags: python, string

How do I make a string repeat itself for example:

instead of writing `print ('---------------------------')` how do I make it something like `print ('-') * 60`?

Comment: Sorry, you can only pick *one* answer as accepted. Pick the one that *you* feel helped you the most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were *so* close:

```
>>> print('-' * 60)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

You need to multiply the `str` value, *not* the return value of the `print()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close - it's

```
print "-" * 60
```

In Python 2, in Python 3, it's

```
print ("-" * 60)
```

Comment: This would work on Python 2, but not on Python 3. The OP must be using Python 3 however, as `print ('-') * 60` would work just fine on Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup, just realized that.